# overflow scroll works unexpected inside table

Tags: html, css

see http://liveweave.com/nZjCNe

I have set table width to window width, it works fine when images inside ul > li is less but when images are large whole window shows scroll, why?
so I have used `style="height:100%;overflow:hidden` for ul .

**html code**

```
<table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" style="max-width:800px" align="center">
<tr height="40px"><td>tab 1</td><td>tab 2</td></tr>
<tr height="calc(100% - 40px)">
    <td colspan="2">
        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">
                    <ul id="image-list" class="scrollimage" style="height:100%;overflow:hidden">
                        <li style=""><img src="img/11.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="101" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/12.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="30" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/13.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="10" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/11.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="30" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/12.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="30" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/13.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="10" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/11.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="30" ></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    <tr height="calc(100% - 40px)"><td></td></tr>
                                    <tr height="40px"><td></td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
                                    <tr height="calc(100% - 40px)"><td></td></tr>
                                    <tr height="40px"><td></td></tr>
                                </table>                            
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="20%">
                    <ul id="image-list" class="scrollimage" style="height:100%;overflow:hidden">
                        <li style=""><img src="img/11.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="101" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/12.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="30" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/13.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="10" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/11.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="30" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/12.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="30" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/13.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="10" ></li>
                        <li style=""><img src="img/11.png" class="draggable-image" alt="top" id="30" ></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**css code**

```
    #image-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    }
    #image-list li {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .draggable-image{
    width:100%
    }
```

please anyone help me to solve it.

Comment: Try to avoid the use of table for layout of the page: use them only for data. My suggest is to rewrite the code using div and percent value for markup.

Comment: yeah i know but using div will be difficult for me

Comment: You're causing yourself all sorts of problems by using tables to control your layout here, you should seriously consider rewriting as @GiacomoPaita said. Also, you're making it even more unmaintainable with all of those inline styles, get them refactored out into a separate CSS file

Comment: yeah but , i have only one page that need to be 3-column for all device and browser size so i prefer using it ?..please tell how to make ul li scrollable

Comment: Try to improve your skills with an initial little effort, try to find the better solution, for example, starting here: http://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq

Comment: but i want 3 colum layout event when resized

Comment: fine i will try it later any way to get solution in my case ?.

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow:scroll` in ul and give it a fixed height like `height:200px`, then your ul will scroll on overflow

```
#image-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: yeah but height will change depending on window size see -http://liveweave.com/NiX3Af